# np.argpartition when sorting 2d arrays and nan

Tags: python, numpy, partitioning

Consult np.argpartition when sorting 2d arrays, can you exclude the influence of nan?

```
Such as:
a = np.array([  1.,  -1.,  nan,   0.,  nan,   2.,   4.,  -2., -10.,  nan])

# Get effective Element Center
np.argpartition(a, (~np.isnan(a)).sum()//2)]
```

But what if it's a 2d array query?